# JSON parsing with Eclipse

Tags: java, json, eclipse

I'm new in java and i have this maybe simple faculty project. I must to parse json with eclipse, so i started but without any success. I don't know how to start when i have a multiple object in json.

I started like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

         FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);


            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
            JSONArray objectArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("product");


            //JSONObject site= jsonSites.getJSONObject(1);

            long elementaryProductId =  (long) jsonObject[0].get("elementaryProductId");
            System.out.println("The id is: " + elementaryProductId);'
```

And thi is my json file:

```
[{  
    "elementaryProductId":1,
    "bonusMalus":30,
    "deductible":500,
    "comprehensive":1,
    "partial":0,
    "legacyPremium":130,
    "product":{  
        "productId":2,
        "garage":"true",
        "constructionYear":1990,
        "region":"East",
        "dateOfBirthYoungest":"1983-06-22",
        "objectValue":25000,
        "type":"Car",
        "insuredObject":{  
            "name":"Car",
            "ownersName":"Jovana",
            "mileage":300000,
            "engineCapacity":120
        },
        "salesProduct":{  
            "salesProductId":3,
            "currency":"EUR",
            "contractStart":"2011-01-01",
            "contractEnd":"2012-01-01"
        },
        "productType":"Car"
    }
},
{  
    "elementaryProductId":1,
    "bonusMalus":5,
    "deductible":100,
    "comprehensive":1,
    "partial":0,
    "legacyPremium":75.38,
    "product":{  
        "productId":2,
        "garage":"true",
        "constructionYear":2005,
        "region":"East",
        "dateOfBirthYoungest":"1999-06-22",
        "objectValue":30000,
        "type":"Car",
        "insuredObject":{  
            "name":"Car",
            "ownersName":"Jelena",
            "mileage":300000,
            "engineCapacity":210
        },
        "salesProduct":{  
            "salesProductId":3,
            "currency":"EUR",
            "contractStart":"2013-01-01",
            "contractEnd":"2014-01-01"
        },
        "productType":"Car"
    }
}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Pepinho. Do you get any error? What are your results compared to your expectations? Please add this to your question by editing.

Comment: What library are you using for JSON parsing?

Comment: Be sure to add the complete code, the full JSON input and the stacktrace of any exception you may have encountered (or the incorrect results vs. the expected ones).

Comment: I'm using json-simple-1.1.1.jar.

Comment: Before that i have errors :JSONArray objectArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("");

Comment: Whats the name of the extrernal array object. Its not product.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't parse JSON (at least not visibly).  You parse JSON in (presumably) Java, and you could have picked any of two dozen different 3rd party packages to do that parsing.  You should specify which you use.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It's quite simple.  Then understand that a JSON "object" maps almost exactly to a Java Map, and a JSON "array" maps almost exactly to a Java List.  But as a newbie you will trip over the difference between, eg, `double` and `Double`.  If you don't understand what I meant by that you might be better off leaving JSON aside for another couple of weeks while you get more familiar with the fundamentals of Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work with the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException{
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File("filename.json"));


    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(reader);
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(0);
    long elementaryProductId = (Long) object.get("elementaryProductId");



    System.out.println("The id is: " + elementaryProductId);
}
```

**Explanation of the above:**

You know the outermost element is an array so parse straight into a `JSONArray`. Next you want to pull out the first element of that array which is a `JSONObject` (its in braces). After that the code should be fairly self explanatory :)

Comment: Have you imported java.io.File;? On that class in eclipse just press ctrl+shift+o (organize imports) and it should sort that out